# Merge 2 schemas from Postgres DBs with different flyways

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, flyway

I currently have 2 databases used by 2 services (let's call them database/service A and database/service B), both of them with their own schemas.

I need to migrate some of the tables from DB A into DB B, once that's all completed re-point service A to service B. I know could easily do the schema migration by using pg_dump utility and that seems to be the "easy" bit.

The problem I have is that both services use Flyway for database version control, hence when I re-point service A to DB B there's a bunch of migrations that are clashing on the same version number because of checksum mismatch.

I've seen that there's a "baseline" functionality in Flyway (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline), but at first look that doesn't seem to be what I need.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: This also comes with another fun task... how to handle the 2 different sets of migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first considering this problem, the immediate answer is that your move from DbB to DbA is done through one migration on top of the existing migrations in DbA. You don't try to modify the database outside of the Flyway process. Instead, you incorporate the Flyway process into your database change. Flyway is very agnostic to the set of changes you introduce. So, you're just adding another change to the existing set. This shouldn't result in a repair or a baseline to get to the required point.

Let's say the last migration for DbA is V6.3__XXX, we just add V6.4__MigratingDbB to our chain of changes. What's in that script is the necessary set of changes. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks Grant, I'm now thinking this probably is the best option, my concern was more about how to keep 2 sets of migrations alive across the 2 services but I do not think this is a good idea. 

What I'm thinking to do is: create a new migration (in service B) containing all the DB A schema changes to replicate the tables I need in DB B, apply the migration, dump the data from those tables, disable Flyway on service A, re-point service A to DB B.

Comment: Seems like a valid approach to me. I would keep the history on DB A in source control for a while, just in case.

Comment: I agree, that was my plan too. Keeping the history of all the migrations applied won't harm.

Answer (score 1):

Grant's answer is definitely the best, but an alternative solution if the database objects for the two services are completely independent, is to have two Flyway configurations which refer to the script collections for each service, and which have distinct history tables. The problem is if there are dependencies between the two services; the migrations from one service would then need to know the current state of play in the other, which could get you in a tangle actually executing them.

Comment: Yes Julia unfortunately that's the situation or better it will become like you say. I explain: the reason of the merge is that service A and B are independent (and so are the DB schemas they use). However, the reason of this "schema merge" is that we need to merge the DBs as well as the services to become just one service. Eventually, refactoring the tables so that they will have relationships on each other. Hence my need to have only one script collection and effectively one history table.